# SFTP directory owned by user

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, sshd, sftp

I am looking to be able to SFTP a file from one linux server to Red Hat 8 server on AWS EC2.

I have created a user called `sftpuser` and want all files that are SFTP'd to this user to land in `/testdata/sftp/incoming/`.

I have managed to get this working only when I make root the owner of both `/testdata` and `/testdata/sftp`, but I need `/testdata` to be owned by another Linux user, and giving any group/other permissions stops the SFTP from working.

```
Match User sftpuser
        ChrootDirectory /testdata/sftp/incoming
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Is it possible to sftp files to that incoming folder but allow another user to own `/testdata`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why do you want `/testdata` directory to be owned by another user? As *sftp* `internal-sftp` used ChrootDirectory requirements, all specified path must be owned by the the *root* user only.

One good way is to change your configuration for `sftpuser` user like:

```
Match User sftpuser
        ChrootDirectory /testdata/sftp/
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

*Note that we removed `incoming` directory*; then reload the configuration:

```
sudo systemctl reload sshd.service
### sudo service ssh reload      ## use this command if not a systemd
```

now create `incoming` directory with that specific `sftpuser` user/group permission individually like:

```
sudo mkdir /testdata/sftp/incoming
sudo chown sftpuser /testdata/sftp/incoming
sudo chmod 755 /testdata/sftp/incoming
```

now, the `sftpuser` have read/write access to `/testdata/sftp/incoming/` path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, people will be sending large files through SFTP to the /testdata/sftp/incoming folder, I have 1TB provisioned to /testdata and all other folders have a combined total of 100gb as a boot volume so I need the file to go directly to a folder within /testdata. Also /testdata needs to be read/writable by another linux service user to read and write data down, not root.